# Cannot update array elements into database in asp.net

Tags: c#, database

I'm updating the values in the database through array but it is updating only last value in array to all rows. What am I doing wrong?

In .cs file

```
BL_HotelDetails hd1 = new BL_HotelDetails();
string[] strResult = strObj.Split(',');
hd1.updateintoRoomNames(hid, strResult);
```

In Bussiness logic Layer

```
public void updateintoRoomNames(int hid, string[] strResult)
{
    DA_HotelDetails hd2 = new DA_HotelDetails();
    hd2.updateintoRommNamesDA(hid,strResult);
}
```

In Data Access Layer

```
public void updateintoRommNamesDA(int hid, string[] strResult)
{
    foreach (string s in strResult) 
    {
        Connection concls = new Connection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string instr = "update tblRoomNames set roomnames='" + s + "' where hid=" + hid + "";

        concls.opencon();
        cmd.CommandText = instr;
        concls.executenonquery(cmd);
        concls.closecon();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post some code, before we can answer.

Comment: You should show us your code. I've got some ideas about what might be happening, but we can't tell for sure without the code.

Comment: are you updating the value of hid in your loop ? If not, this function works as per the code written.

Comment: I think u need a better WHERE condition

Comment: First, you need to post some code in order for us to understand what you are asking exactly. What I can say is, you should take `Connection concls = new Connection();` out of your loop because you don' t need to establish a connection at every loop iteration. Check your hid parameter. It might be causing the problem.

Comment: no i need that condition only..

Comment: Which database you are using SQL SERVER or else. IF SQL SERVER, please check your code , I think it got errors. Here 's correct code
            SqlConnection concls = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string instr = "update tblRoomNames set roomnames='" + s + "' where hid=" + hid + "";

            concls.Open();
            
            cmd.CommandText = instr;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            concls.Close();

Comment: hid parameter is correct.The correct value is coming in hid after debuging.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be ok .
Here how it's working

Say strResult has three values 'Value1','Value2',Value3'
and hid=5

after first iteration the roomnames will be 'Value1' where hid =5

after 2nd iteration roomnames ='Value2' where hid =5
after 3rd iteration roomnames='Value3' where hid =5

as a result you will see roomnames='Value3'

**If you want to change roomnames for each value in strResult array then you should use another array of integers holding hid which will correspond to strResult**

**UPDATE**

I would suggest , create an array of Integers for storing hid values like you have created an array of String strResult.

```
    int[] intNameIDs = = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };
    int hid=22;

    public void updateintoRoomNames(int hid,int[] intNameIDs, string[] strResult)
    {
        DA_HotelDetails hd2 = new DA_HotelDetails();
        hd2.updateintoRommNamesDA(hid,intNameIDs, strResult);
    }


    public void updateintoRommNamesDA(int hid,int[] intNameIDs, string[] strResult)
    {
        int nameidIndex = 0;//index for intHids array. 
        foreach (string s in strResult)
        {
            Connection concls = new Connection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string instr = "update tblRoomNames set roomnames='" + s + "' where nameid=" + intNameIDs[nameidIndex] + " and Hid=" + hid;

            concls.opencon();
            cmd.CommandText = instr;
            concls.executenonquery(cmd);
            concls.closecon();

            nameidIndex++;//move to next.
        }
    }
```

Comment: how should i do that?Can you plz tell me?

Comment: i have same hid for all rows.my columns in table are hid nameid roomname. Lets say 1st row->22 1 A103 2nd row->22 2 A103 3rd row->22 3 A103 and so on.Insted of A103 i want to update A101 a102 a103 resp in roomname column.

Comment: Don't you have any thing to tell?

Comment: I was away from system.Answer is updated, you will have to add nameids array and hid in where clause.

Comment: you can make another function/method to get nameid of roomnames. also.Once you got it pass it to function updateintoRoomNames() in DAL.

Comment: Or if it is possible for you to send me Complete project.

Comment: in .cs file ->List<Entity_HotelDetails> cls =new List<Entity_HotelDetails>();
            cls=hd1.selectRoomNameID(hid);         in BA Layer-> public List<Entity_HotelDetails> selectRoomNameID(int hid)
        {
            List<Entity_HotelDetails> clas1 = new List<Entity_HotelDetails>();
            DA_HotelDetails cls = new DA_HotelDetails();
            clas1 = cls.selectRoomNameIdDA(hid);
            return clas1;
        }

Comment: in DAL->> public List<Entity_HotelDetails> selectRoomNameIdDA(int hid)
        {
           List<Entity_HotelDetails> cls1 = new List<Entity_HotelDetails>();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            Connection concls = new Connection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string instr = "select nameid where hid=" + hid + "";
            concls.opencon();
            cmd.CommandText = instr;
            dr = concls.executequery(cmd);
            cls1 = createListget(dr);
            concls.closecon();
            return cls1;
    } i have done that is it correct way ?

Comment: createListget() is still missing.For single value of hid you will get one or more nameid ?

Comment: int[] intNameIDs = = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };
in this u r taking 3,4,5 but my maneid is auto incremented

Comment: yes you got it. it will not matter if you have **nameid** auto incremented. Array of intNameIDs should contain the values and you will hit the ground.

Comment: public List<Entity_HotelDetails> createListget(SqlDataReader dr)
        {
            List<Entity_HotelDetails> clist = new List<Entity_HotelDetails>();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Entity_HotelDetails Ecls1 = new Entity_HotelDetails();
                if (dr["hid"] != DBNull.Value)
                Ecls1.HID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["hid"]);

Comment: if (dr["nameid"] != DBNull.Value)
                    Ecls1.NAMEID = Convert.ToString(dr["nameid"]);
                if (dr["roomnames"] != DBNull.Value)
                    Ecls1.ROOMNAMES = Convert.ToString(dr["roomnames"]);

                if (dr["hid"] != DBNull.Value)
                    Ecls1.HID =  Convert.ToInt32(dr["hid"]);



                clist.Add(Ecls1);
            }
            return clist;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Based on our disscussion. you can do update like this.

```
    public void updateintoRommNamesDA(List<Entity_HotelDetails> updatedList)
    {

        foreach (Entity_HotelDetails s in updatedList)
        {
            Connection concls = new Connection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string instr = "update tblRoomNames set roomnames='" + s.ROOMNAMES + "' where nameid=" + s.NAMEID + " and Hid=" + s.HID;

            concls.opencon();
            cmd.CommandText = instr;
            concls.executenonquery(cmd);
            concls.closecon();


        }
    }
```

Comment: In debug mode, put s.ROOMNAMES   s.NAMEID    s.HID     in watch window to see their values. if their values are correct or not.

Comment: IN function selectRoomNameIdDA() change the line    string instr = "select nameid where hid=" + hid + ""; to Like this    string instr = "select nameid,Hid,Roomnames where hid=" + hid + "";